# Regex for matching alternating sequences

Tags: java, regex

I'm working in Java and having trouble matching a repeated sequence.  I'd like to match something like:

```
a.b.c.d.e.f.g.
```

and be able to extract the text between the delimiters (e.g. return abcdefg) where the delimiter can be multiple non-word characters and the text can be multiple word characters.  Here is my regex so far:

```
([\\w]+([\\W]+)(?:[\\w]+\2)*)
```

(Doesn't work)

I had intended to get the delimiter in group 2 with this regex and then use a replaceAll on group 1 to exchange the delimiter for the empty string giving me the text only.  I get the delimiter, but cannot get all the text.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please specify what distinguishes the part that you want to capture from the surroundings, and what kind of non-word characters you want to act as delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `(\w+)(\W+|$)` with `$1`. Make sure that global flag is turned on.

It replaces a sequence of word chars followed by a sequence of non-word-chars or end-of-line with the sequence of words.

```
String line = "Am.$#%^ar.$#%^gho.$#%^sh";
line = line.replaceAll("(\\w+)(\\W+|$)", "$1");
System.out.println(line);//prints my name
```

Comment: Trying line = line.replaceAll("([\\w]+)([\\W]+)", "\1"); but it is producing only the string "g" (the last letter of the input)

Comment: use `$1` for replacement. `\1` is for backreferences within the regex - that was a typo :(

Comment: Check @Ruben's answer. `(\\w+)\\W+` will be enough - last part needn't be replaced. <looks for something to hit me on the head with>

Answer (score 1):

Replace `(\w+)\W+` by `$1`

Comment: oops... u r right, this is enough. What was I thinking matching the last part with a `$` and making it look more complicated than it should be? +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `String.split`?

Comment: The problem is that the text will occur within a larger body that won't have the regular pattern.

Comment: I guess you need to modify your example to show the irregularity. For now I still don't see why `"yourStr".split(/\W+/)` isn't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not ..

- find all occurences of `(\w+)` and then concatenate them; or
- find all non word characters `(\W+)` and then use [Matcher.html#replaceAll](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)) with an empty string?

Comment: There are some non-word characters in the input that I care about so replacing all of them will not work as I desire.  I need to only strip them when they follow this particular pattern. For a sequence of 4 characters or more (e.g. a.b.)